# When there are some zeros in input vector, run the biLstm model will get a 'floating error 8'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I do the padding process by myself, so there some 0 values in 'debate', 'reason', 'claim' or 'warrant'. Put into the BiLSTM architecture will get the 'floating error 8' without any other reminder.

This error means some numbers divide by 0 or the index is out of range.

but in the model, there shouldn't be any number divided by 0.

Here is the code:

```
debate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,48,300])
reason = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,48,300])
claim = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,48,300])
warrant = tf.placeholder(tfenter code here.float32,[None,48,300])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2])

n_hidden = 300

w = weight_variable([n_hidden,2])
b = bias_variable([2])
def bilstm(x, weights, biases):

    lstm_f = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias = 1.0)
    lstm_b = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias = 1.0)

    (alloutputs, output_states) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(lstm_f, lstm_b, x, dtype = tf.float32)
    (outputs, state) = output_states
    (output_state_fw, output_state_bw) = state

    return tf.matmul(tf.add(output_state_fw, output_state_bw), weights) + biases
final_representation = tf.concat([debate,reason,claim,warrant],1)

prediction = bilstm(final_representation,w,b)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=prediction))

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

When I put the same input into the normal RNN architecture, it could work.
Here is the RNN code which could run.

```
def RNN(X,weights,biases):
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n_hidden,use_peepholes=True)
    #final_state[0] cell state
    #final_state[1] hidden_state
    outputs,final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell,X,dtype=tf.float32)
    results = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(final_state[1],weights)+biases)
    return results
```

Could anyone tell me what happened? Did I misunderstand biLSTM model? There should not be any number divided by 0 in biLSTM!

Thanks in advance.